# Seo Wordpress Pages on google

Tags: seo

I'm really noob on SEO world, and I can't achive this result:
[image]

I'm working on my site and it dosen't show on google, but if I look for site:mysite.it it's on but it's just the home page. Look here:

[image]

What I have to look for? Sorry but don't rate me wrong, I want to learn. 
So in google page I can see every page ? I can't put them under my homepage, I hope you understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: When searching for `costruzioniao` google thinks you just misspelled `costruzioni`. It doesn't think of it as being an independent search term yet. This should get better with time, especially if you get more links pointing to your domain.

Second thing: Your first screenshot shows a search result with [Site links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). Google generates them when it thinks direct linking deeper into your page will be helpful for the user. They won't appear if youmake a search of the kind `site:yourdomain.com`. If your website has good content pages with a good structure and google is able to recognize it, they will be created eventually. There is no way to force google to do it and you can't controll it exactly. But there are ways to help google to understand which pages are important. Using [Sitemaps/XML Sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) and a good semantic link structure within your website helps google to recognise its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry It will take a while to get your site shown in google. Just keep working on following the SEO tips , which you can find tons of topics if you searched google. You can read this [Here](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/simple-guide-to-seo/)